# Hide Files From Search

Tags: search

How do I hide files from the search? Files are showing up on the results page, but the extension is stripped, so they return a 404. I'd like to either hide the files, or fix the URL returned by search to include the extension. By "files" I mean uploaded files.Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can we have a bit more information? Source Code... etc..

Comment: Please post your relevant template code.